# Store php foreach loop in string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

We have an Array Name `valArray` which is something like this :

```
$valArray = array (
             name => 'Rahul',
             Address => 'New Delhi',
             Pass => '1234',
             class => '10th',
             School => 'DPS',
             Roll => '134567',
           )
```

which generates dynamicaly, So, Actually we want is to run this type of `sql query`,

```
$query = "insert into table_name set
          foreach($valArray as $key => $value) {
            $key = "$value",
          }
         ";
```

and Statically which should be something like this :

```
$query = "insert into table_name set
              name = 'Rahul',
              Address = 'New Delhi',
              Pass = '1234',
              class = '10th',
              School = 'DPS',
              Roll = '134567'
        ";
```

I Know this is `syntactically` wrong but is there any way to perform this type of action.

Comment: be uber careful if these are raw user imputed values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $sql = "insert into $table(" . implode(',', array_keys($valArray)) . " values('" . implode("','", array_values($valArray)) . "')";
```

the call to `array_values` isn't necessary, but better illustrates the idea I think

edit: quoted values; they should be escaped too

Comment: only thing missing is the values should be quuoted

Comment: @twentylemon What will be happen when we will use sql `update` command.